# How to get list of Items with ids in NHibernate

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-web-api, nhibernate

I have a list of item ids `playerIds` (they come from Redis),I Want to get Objects (`User`) of them through NHibernate , but the way i have written it is not optimized it think.

here is my code :

```
List<int> playerIds = redisRespnse.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    List<User> TopPlayers = new List<User>();
    for (int i = 0; i < playerIds.Count; i++)
    {
        var player = session.Query<User>()
            .Where(user => user.Id == playerIds[i])
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (player != null)
        {
            TopPlayers.Add(player);
        }
    }
    var finalResponse = new GetLeaderBoardResponse(TopPlayers);
    return Ok(finalResponse);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't NHibernate support `.Contains()` method? In EF6 you can do `var topPlayers = usersDbSet.Where(u => playerIds.Contains(u.Id)).ToArray();`. Note that with your approach you do N SQL queries instead of 1.

Comment: It works, but is it optimized?, i dont know for a large table of `Users`. it should iterate through all of them to find the answer.

Comment: Afaik, `Contains` generates a query like this "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id in { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ... }". It is far more optimized than your approach :) You can profile SQL and check for generated queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nhibernate linq provider supports .Contains

```
List<int> playerIds = redisRespnse.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
        var players = session.Query<User>()
            .Where(user => playerIds.Contains(user.Id))
            .Select(user => user).ToList();

    }
    var finalResponse = new GetLeaderBoardResponse(players);
    return Ok(finalResponse);
}
```